# PowerApp Filter with empty Dropdown's inputs, fulltext search and between time date's

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have problem put all code together for filtering my `Gallery`.

I have 3x `DropDown` input's, one `text` input and double date picker's. When i no use any filter, i want to show all items in `Gallery`. My idea was, create code for each type of filter and put them together. But my code show all item in gallery but no filtering.

For null value in DropDown ussing `vardd1Blank, vardd2Blank, vardd3Blank`, next `Sort` and `IF` statement

```
With(
{
    vardd1Blank: IsBlank(dd1Search.Selected.Value),
    vardd2Blank: IsBlank(dd2Search.Selected.Value),
    vardd3Blank: IsBlank(dd3Search.Selected.Value)
},
Sort(
    If(
        vardd1Blank,
        galleryItems,
        vardd2Blank,
        galleryItems,
        vardd3Blank,
        galleryItems,
        Filter(
            galleryItems,
                StartsWith(
                Note,
                txtSearchNote.Text ) || (IsBlank(txtSearchNote.Text)),
                IsBlankOrError(txtNote.Text) || txtSearchNote.Text in Note.Value,
                'dd1'.Value = dd1Search.Selected.Value || 
                'dd2'.Value = dd2Search.Selected.Value || 
                'dd3'.Value = dd3Search.Selected.Value,
                ('Date' > dp1) && ('Date' < dp2)
         )
       ),
       'ID',
       Descanding
       )
       )
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula for `items` property of gallery control:

```
Sort(
    Filter(
        galleryItems,
        IsBlankOrError(txtSearchNote.Text) || StartsWith(Note,txtSearchNote.Text),
        IsBlankOrError(txtNote.Text) || txtNote.Text in Note.Value,
        IsBlankOrError(dd1Search.Selected.Value) || 'dd1'.Value = dd1Search.Selected.Value,
        IsBlankOrError(dd2Search.Selected.Value) || 'dd2'.Value = dd2Search.Selected.Value,
        IsBlankOrError(dd3Search.Selected.Value) || 'dd3'.Value = dd3Search.Selected.Value,
        'Date' > dp1 && 'Date' < dp2
    ),
    'ID',
    Descanding
)
```